# F# Powerpack and Entity Framework: How refactor a common part of two queries

Tags: entity-framework, f#, powerpack

I have two queries:

```
 member private x.CheckIfUserExistsUsingId(userId:int, context:StoryBoardContext) =
  <@ context.Users 
     |> Seq.exists (fun currentUser -> currentUser.Id = userId) @>
```

And

```
member private x.FindUserById(userId:int, context:StoryBoardContext) =
 <@ context.Users 
    |> Seq.filter(fun currentUser -> currentUser.Id = userId) 
    |> Seq.head @>
```

I'd like to refactor this so that the two

```
 fun currentUser -> currentUser.Id = userId
```

Can be one method like:

```
member private x.IfUserIdMatches (userId:int) = 
  fun (currentUser:User) -> currentUser.Id = userId
```

And then use it:

```
member private x.CheckIfUserExistsUsingId(userId:int, context:StoryBoardContext) =
  <@ context.Users 
     |> Seq.exists (x.IfUserIdMatches (userId)) @>
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
The following construct was used in query but is not recognised by the F#-to-LINQ query translator...
```

Which makes me think my signature for the method is poorly constructed. Being new to F# it has me a little confused since I'm positive this can be done in C# using a method that returns a Func.  However, I understand that there are differences right off the bat since F# is using a different library to construct linq queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you change your method to return `Expr`

```
member private x.IfUserIdMatches (userId:int) = 
  <@ fun (currentUser:User) -> currentUser.Id = userId @>
```

and use splicing?

```
member private x.CheckIfUserExistsUsingId(userId:int, context:StoryBoardContext) =
  <@ context.Users 
      |> Seq.exists %(x.IfUserIdMatches (userId)) @>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the % operator has something to do with how it evaluates the method return?

Comment: Yes, it inserts one expression into another. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx